# is there a way to limit the amount of rows that get affected by an UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, pervasive

just wondering if there is any way for me to limit the amount of rows
which will be affected by an UPDATE statement....I was thinking of using something like a LIMIT statement but there's no such thing in PERVASIVE, any tips?

thank you

Comment: Since you don't control the order of the matching data found by the WHERE clause in the update, this doesn't really make a lot of sense.  Are you just trying to avoid running an update against millions of rows?

Comment: @Mark Mann HI MARK, this is exactly the issue, i have a UPDATE statement that im testing against a rather large table and just wish to limit the amount of time it will take just so i can test it out first...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this would work...

UPDATE TableName
    SET ColumnName = value
WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM TableName WHERE CONDITION)

Make TOP 100 whatever your "limit" is.  Then, just update the WHERE clause appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The `TOP 100` idea can work but depending on your data, it may skew either testing the correctness or performance. It can also be hard to write. I think adding a `RANDOM`-based clause works a little better.

```
UPDATE t SET c = blah 
  WHERE (/* whatever bunch of stuff */) 
  AND Random()<0.01 /* 1 percent */
```

This works if your DB's random gives a value between zero and one, and can be modified for different random functions and densities.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just being careful, why not just count the rows you would update?

```
select count(*) from MYTABLE WHERE ...some condition...;
```

If the count is sufficiently low, this is practically cut & paste to the update:

```
update MYTABLE set col1 = val1, ... WHERE ...some condition...;
```

Put into your scripting language, pl/sql, or stored procedure as is appropriate.